# Grouped Horizontal Bar Chart - Group Labels not using group space

Tags: ios-charts

I am using iOS-charts to build a horizontal bar chart.  The chart itself is as expected, but the group label is not aligned with the center as expected.  And progressively the offset gets worse.

I've figured that it is not taking into account the group spacing that I specify.

[image]

As you can see from the image, in this small sample, there are 7 groups but 8 labels

How can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you pls post your Chart code so we can get idea whats going wrong ?

Comment: also tag language for which you are expecting answer Swift or Objective-C ?

Comment: I've actually used another charting library as this was becoming very time consuming